# How to style the react-leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, popup, react-leaflet

Is it possible to style the popup that comes with react-leaflet.js.org?  I've been hacking away with the styles but can you get ui templates for the popup/ or what is the correct way to totally change how the popup looks?

**Code snippet**

```
<Marker
    key={message._id}
    position={[message.latitude, message.longitude]}
    icon="">

      <Popup className="request-popup">
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </Popup> 
</Marker>
```

I would like to style the popup to look something like the following

[image: desired popup design]

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manipulate the built-in appearance of leaflet's popup via the class you assigned `request-popup` to change for instance the border-radius of popup

```
.request-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

To write custom text and give it your personal style I would recommend creating a file called f.i popupStyles.js. There you declare all your popuup style. Then you import it in the Map comp and write your one html. Use bootstrap to achieve desired margins and other goodies.

popupStyles.js

```
const popupContent = {
  textAlign: "center",
  height: "350px",
  marginTop: "30px"
};
const popupHead = {
  fontWeight: "bold",
  fontSize: "22px"
};

const popupText = {
  fontSize: "15px",
  marginBottom: "20px"
};

const okText = {
  fontSize: "15px"
};

export { popupContent, popupHead, popupText, okText };
```

and then in the comp

```
import { popupContent, popupHead, popupText, okText } from "./popupStyles";

<Marker position={center} icon={defaultMarker}>
    <Popup className="request-popup">
      <div style={popupContent}>
        <img
          src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicolor-arrows-checks/24/149_check_ok-512.png"
          width="150"
          height="150"
        />
        <div className="m-2" style={popupHead}>
          Success!
        </div>
        <span style={popupText}>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
          enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
          nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </span>
        <div className="m-2" style={okText}>
          Okay
        </div>
      </div>
    </Popup>
  </Marker>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/1q437z36n7)

Answer (score 5):

I just tried to style it with Styled Components and... it works awesome! :)

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import { Icon } from "leaflet";

const StyledPop = styled(Popup)`
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0;
  .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
`;

const icon = new Icon({
  iconUrl: "/marker.svg",
  iconSize: [25, 25],
});

export const MapView = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);

  const handleOnContextMenu = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      setPosition([event.latlng.lat, event.latlng.lng]);
    },
    [setPosition]
  );

  return (
    <Container>
      <Map
        center={[50.061252, 19.915738]}
        zoom={15}
        oncontextmenu={handleOnContextMenu}
      >
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />

        {position && (
          <StyledPop position={position} onClose={() => setPosition(null)}>
            <div>
              <h2>menu</h2>
            </div>
          </StyledPop>
        )}

        {position && <Marker position={position} icon={icon} />}
      </Map>
    </Container>
  );
};
```